# 301 redirect from webpage to wordpress page in the same root

Tags: php, htaccess, redirect

I installed WordPress in my root directory `http://coinauctionshelp.com`. I want to redirect pages in the root to the new wordpress pages using an .htaccess file like this

301 redirect

```
http://coinauctionshelp.com/United_States_Coin_Mintages_Price_Guides.html
http://coinauctionshelp.com/us-coin-values/
```

When I tried to do that I got a 500 internal server error so is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: Have you tested after clearing the cache or from another browser or using an incognito window (Chrome) or private (FF)?  Try a redirect trace to see what's happening with the 301.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the trace results.

http://coinauctionshelp.com/United_States_Coin_Mintages_Price_Guides.html

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 01 Jul 2016 22:24:27 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Mon, 25 Apr 2016 21:39:43 GMT
ETag: "38150-117-5315603b9a5c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 279
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close

Comment: Please [merge your two accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can edit or leave comments on your question.

Answer (score 0):

When I create a .htaccess in my root directory to redirect a page in the root to a page in the wordpress directory then it changes the .htaccess of the wordpress. So this is what I have so far.

I can fix the 500 by eliminating my .htaccess and rebuilding the .htaccess of my wordpress.